# JS - I don't understand why this declaration of object doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I'm just starting out learning some JS and I have a very simple but confusing question. I've tried to debug my code to see how this works and why it works the way it does but I just don't get it. Below I have my function along with a sample input of `employeeData`.

```
function transformEmployeeData(employeeData) {
  var result = [];
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < employeeData.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < employeeData[i].length; j++) {
      obj[employeeData[i][j][0]] = employeeData[i][j][1];
    }
    result.push(obj);
  }
  return result;
}

var input = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
]

/* Expected Results -
[
    {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
] 

Actual Results - 
[
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'},
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
]*/
```

I know how to fix my code to get the desired results by moving the `var obj = {};` line right after the `for` loop of `i`. What I don't understand is why does the above code not work? After the `i = 0` finishes, the obj holds the first expected input and pushes it into the result array. But then it pushes the Mary array and over writes the rest and I end up with the actual result. Couple of questions. Why does my initial object that is correct holding data of `Joe` disappear from my array and why does the object holding the `Mary` data get put in twice? If I'm understanding my code correctly; the `for` loop for `i` should only iterate twice meaning that there should only ever be two objects pushed into it but why do I end up with 2 `Mary` objects inside? And lastly why does the declaration of a new object variable need to be inside the initial `for` loop?

Comment: You only ever have one object. You push it multiple times to an array. The array doesn't contain different objects, it contains the same object multiple times. You are editing the object, hence, you are editing the first element of your result array (and the second, and any other times you pushed that one object to the array - because they are all the same).

Comment: Pushing the object into the array _does not duplicate it or create a new object_.  You only create it once, all references to it are the same object, and when you update it in a loop you update the only object you have.

Comment: Ah.... makes total sense. Thanks everyone - I thought it was something simple!

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60127083/7719176) below to your question, it is working example, accept the answer if you feel like it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are learning, here is my 2c to your learning journey. Instead of endless nested loops, try to embrace the gems of functional programming, namely, [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Using them, you can achieve what you were doing in a much more elegant (and often times, faster) manner:

```
var input = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
]

var transformedInput = input.map(function(el) {
    return el.reduce(function(result, elel) {
        result[elel[0]] = elel[1];
        return result;
    }, {});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has only one mistake otherwise it is ok,

**JavaScript Objects are passed by reference**, but you are pushing the same Object in every iteration, so the next object overrides the last one and you got the same object in all iteration.

So what you have to do is **declare `var obj;` outside the loop and put the `obj = {};` inside the first for loop, so that a new object is created each time loop iterates**,

See my below working example:

```js
function transformEmployeeData(employeeData) {
  var result = [];
  var obj;

  for (var i = 0; i < employeeData.length; i++) {
    obj = {};

    for (var j = 0; j < employeeData[i].length; j++) {
      obj[employeeData[i][j][0]] = employeeData[i][j][1];
    }
    result.push(obj);
  }
  return result;
}

var input = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
]
console.log(transformEmployeeData(input));
```